# Adam optimizer takes much longer on the almost the same model to apply gradients

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, profiling

I have two models that are almost specular, if not for the last layer, where one is `Dense(1, "linear")` and for the other one is `Dense(4, "softmax")`.. and the code is the following:

```
gradient_agent = tape.gradient(loss_agent, agent.trainable_weights)
gradient_value = tape.gradient(loss_value, value.trainable_weights)

# Do something to the gradients

optimizer_agent.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_agent, agent.trainable_weights))
optimizer_value.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_value, value.trainable_weights))
```

However, when I profile my code, I get the following statistics:

```
% Time       | Line
    29.3     |  optimizer_agent.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_agent, agent.trainable_weights))
    1.6      |  optimizer_value.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_value, value.trainable_weights))
```

Why does it takes so much to apply the first gradient?

It seems it's some TensorFlow optimization, because if I switch the lines, now it's the other gradient slow to be applied. However, this code is not in a `@tf.function`, so what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to swap the order of the two and the time for the first to be executed is still long, I would say there is nothing wrong with the Adam optimizer or your code.

The lazy vs eager effect probably cause your timer to measure all the preparations included in the first call to the optimizer.

I would ignore this for now or try to optimize in other ways. You could try other optimizers if you think they will be as effective.

Comment: yes but I don't see why 2 different instantiations of a class should take advantage one from the other...

Comment: The preparations needed for them to run will be done only when they are needed. So when the first class is starting to need those preparations, they will take time to actually be prepared (instead of being done when you instructed them to be done - this is how lazy computing works - work is done when needed, not when it is instructed). So when the first instance need the preparations, they take time to complete and that is included in your measured time. I hope this clarify the eager vs lazy computation issue.